# Name of this Instrumental Track I've been trying to identify for almost a decade

Tags: instrumental

I have been looking for the name of this song (as well as the artist) for nine years. Here's a link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwLTAjBJlFk

The person who posted it says in the comments that they got it on a mix CD with no track listings or artist names. There have been a lot of guesses but I've followed them all up to the best of my ability and found artists that seemed like they could have made it (Aubrey Ashburn for Dragon Age or Aeone, for example) but have never actually found the song.

There seems to also be some trance music (I think that's what you'd describe the genre) that has what appears to be a heavily remixed version of these same vocals, like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpBwB8VTcXo, but I haven't been able to find out where the vocals came from originally.

If anyone has any ideas, or knows the song, please, PLEASE let me know. This song is like my white whale.

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can tell the mix CD is called *Deep & Tech #2* and the song is called 'Solitude' from Baset [update: Baset said he doesn't know the singer used for this track].

Baset can be found on FB: https://www.facebook.com/Basetmusicofficial/

I don't know the name of the person singing though.

https://soundcloud.com/1103musik/baset-solitude